# How to check if any elements in array contains in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays of objects. I need to check if items are contained in another array. If one of them is not contain will be false.

```
 const arr = [
            {full_name: 'Test'},
            {full_name: 'Test1'},
            {full_name: 'Test2'},
        ]

        const arr1 = [
            {full_name: 'Test'},
            {full_name: 'Test1'},
            {full_name: 'Test2'},
            {full_name: 'Test3'},
            {full_name: 'Test4'},
            {full_name: 'Test5'},
            {full_name: 'Test6'},
        ]
```

If arr1 contain Test Test1 Test2 will be true, if one of them not contains will be false.

I think I need some operator

Comment: Try searching for duplicate questions.

Answer (score 0):

My approach using every and some array functions:

```js
const arr = [
    {full_name: 'Test'},
    {full_name: 'Test1'},
    {full_name: 'Test6'},
]

const arr1 = [
    {full_name: 'Test'},
    {full_name: 'Test1'},
    {full_name: 'Test2'},
    {full_name: 'Test3'},
    {full_name: 'Test4'},
    {full_name: 'Test5'},
    {full_name: 'Test6'},
]

console.log(arr.every(item => {
  return arr1.some( i2 => i2.full_name == item.full_name)
}))
```